# Ambiguous survey question

Tags: discussion, feedback, stack-overflow-developer-survey

From [Stack Overflow's Annual User Survey 2012](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/GQGJWSS):  "Have you visited / Are you aware of Stack Overflow Careers?"  Yes or No.

I'm not sure what the expected answer should be for anyone (like myself) who is aware of, but has never visited Stack Overflow Careers.

Comment: Isn't that splitting hairs? If you have visited, or are aware of Careers, click "yes". If you have neither, click "no."

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo.  It reads as if it should be two separate questions to me.

Comment: @Dan I guess they don't care about the distinction - they just want to know whether you've heard of it

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. In that case, I'd call it badly worded; since if you've visited it you're aware by definition.

Comment: @Bobby: I _know about_ Careers, but have never visited. Therefore, my answer to the survey question is "No I haven't and yes I am" which isn't covered by ()Yes or ()No.

Answer (score 6):

The answer would be "Yes" =)

The implication of the question is that if either is true (you've visited OR you're aware), answer yes.  Otherwise, answer no.

Comment: Ah, the logical "or."  My favorite.  If the question reads "Have you visited SO careers or is the sky plaid?" the answer would still be "yes" :)

Comment: @David Haha, indeed!  I think the fact that the "/" is *implying* the "or" is likely the cause of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I do understand the question asked. Some won't - and I guess that is much like the rest of SO. Questions can be good or bad, but reacting to poorly written surveys shouldn't be any different to any other question on SO; ignore it if you don't get it.

A feature request for flagging bad surveys, maybe? ;-)

Comment: With a poorly written question you can leave comments asking for clarification, or edit to make it clearer for others.  For the survey posting on meta is the closest equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

If you are filling out a survey (to my knowledge, for most surveys) they want someone who's opinions have not been altered by other peoples opinions. If you are taking this survey in order to gain something free, I would say no. If this is a legitimate survey that you are required to take for some sort of job or something, I would say yes.

Comment: It's from the official SO 2012 survey.  Edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: @DanNeely Personally, I would honestly fill out an SO survey

Comment: What makes you think my intent was otherwise?  My confusion was over how to map objective values (my use and awareness of SO Careers) onto the provided answers; not what the 'right' answer to a subjective question should be.